# Apache flink - usage of TumblingProcessingTimeWindow with TimeCharacteristic.EventTime

Tags: java, apache-flink

It looks like TumblingProcessingTimeWindow always uses "Ingestion time".
Is there any way to force windowing on the event time?

My use-case is quite simple I recieve events that contain "event timestamp", and want them to be aggregated based on event time.

E.g. in following code I expect 2 outputs:

```
public class WindowExample {

private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    DataStreamSource<Bean> beans = env.fromElements(
        new Bean(1, 1, "12:00:00"),
        new Bean(1, 2, "12:00:03"),
        new Bean(1, 1, "12:00:04"),  //window of 3 sec trigger here
        new Bean(1, 2, "12:00:05"),
        new Bean(1, 3, "12:00:06"),
        new Bean(1, 3, "12:00:07")   //window of 3 sec trigger here
    );

    beans.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AscendingTimestampExtractor<Bean>() {
        @Override public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Bean element) {
            return element.getTs();
        }
    })
        .keyBy("id")
        .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(3)))
        .max("value")
        .addSink(new SinkFunction<Bean>() {

            @Override public void invoke(Bean value, Context context) {
                System.out.println("Sync on: "+value);
            }
        });
    env.execute("Windowing test");
}

public static class Bean {

    private int id;
    private int value;
    private long ts;

    public Bean() {
    }

    Bean(int id, int value, String time) throws ParseException {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.ts = FORMAT.parse(time).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    }

    long getTs() {
        return ts;
    }
    // other getters and setters
}
```

}

Comment: _"in following code I expect 2 outputs"_ -- Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's a bunch of my code, it doesn't work, can someone help me figure it out"_ are considered off-topic. What specific output are you expecting? What are you getting instead? Why do you think it is incorrect? Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information, and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink allows the use of processing time windows with event time streams, because there are legitimate use cases for that. But if you do want event time windowing, you need to ask for it. In this case you should be using `TumblingEventTimeWindows`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just have not realized that I used the wrong window.

Comment: I have another question related to the topic, maybe you can answer that straight away:
Imagine doing aggregation based on Event Time, with a live stream of data - will the watermark generated for an event with certain key trigger the window operation on windows for other keys?

Comment: You should create a new stackoverflow question for this new question.